# No firewall, yet cant access an open port remotely

Tags: networking

I have no firewall. I am unable to access some ports (local). When running `netstat`, all ports EXCEPT the ones with proto TCP6 can be accessed. this includes SSH and telnet, yet remote desktop shows under TCP6, and I can not access it from another system (my router has ipv6 support). Please help

Comment: The router is configured to forward the ports and the ISP supports IPv6?

Comment: yes. also, im doing it locally (as mentioned in the question), so no public ports